# ELK stack - Lucene issue with query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, grafana

I am trying to have this data in Kibana and Grafana.

I have got this query:

```
type:one AND ManagedBy:two AND (table:three OR table:four) AND NOT status:five
```

I use this same option - unique count in Kibana and also in Grafana.

Results:
Kibana: 5140
Grafana: 2611

Why? I have got this same timeframe also for "Today".
I see that in Grafana I have results only from "table:three". So something should be wrong with this query.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a way to extract the generated query that's being sent from Kibana and Grafana to compare them?

Comment: Query for Kibana and Grafana is the same. I did ctrl+c and ctrl+v. I tried to contact with some people from my side and they told me that Grafana cannot visualize all data from db which is metric db. I am not sure if it is true. To sum up --> This same query -> diffrent results

Comment: I resolved that case.

Solution: Data in Grafana were from diffrent time. table:three was from 3:30, four from 4:39. I put interval time for 8h and for now everything is working fine.